# How to use MuMIn::dredge on models in nested data frame (edit: with parallel processing)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, tidyverse, glmmtmb, mumin

I have many glmmTMB models in a nested data frame that I would like to dredge iteratively, but I get this result even when trying to dredge a single model:

> Error in eval(call("is.data.frame", gmCall$data), gmEnv) :
> object '"is.data.frame"' not found

Fitting the same models outside of the nested data frame works without issue as long as the data are saved as an object in the environment. Is there a fix to use nested data frames? Or maybe a list if necessary? I'd rather not have dozens of standalone data frames and accompanying models floating around.

Example using `mtcars` dataset:

```
# Example model to fit
mod_fx <- function(x) {
  glmmTMB(mpg ~ disp + drat + wt, 
          data = x,
          family = gaussian(),
          na.action = "na.fail")
}

# Grouping and nesting data
dat <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(mod = map(data, mod_fx))

# Model summary works fine, but note: Data = x
# Related to problem?
summary(dat$mod[[1]])

# Dredge fails
dred_dat <- dredge(dat$mod[[1]],
                   rank = "AICc",
                   evaluate = T)

# Dredge does work when same model is built with separate data frame object stored in environment, not a nested data frame.
dat2 <- filter(mtcars, cyl == 6)

m1 <- glmmTMB(mpg ~ disp + drat + wt, 
        data = dat2,
        family = gaussian(),
        na.action = "na.fail")

summary(m1) # Same model results, (data = dat2), but dredge works:

dred_dat <- dredge(m1,
                   rank = "AICc",
                   evaluate = T)

# This also fails without data stored as separate object
m3 <- glmmTMB(mpg ~ disp + drat + wt, 
              data = filter(mtcars, cyl == 6),
              family = gaussian(),
              na.action = "na.fail")

summary(m3) # Data: filter(mtcars, cyl == 6)

dred_dat <- dredge(m3,
                   rank = "AICc",
                   evaluate = T)
# Error in dredge(m3, rank = "AICc", evaluate = T) : 'global.model' uses "data" that is a function value: use a variable instead
```

Edit:

Failed attempt to add parallel processing to Ben's solution:

```
clust <- try(makeCluster(detectCores()-1))
invisible(clusterCall(clust, "library", "glmmTMB",
                      character.only = TRUE))

dfun <- function(x) {
  g1 <- glmmTMB(mpg ~ disp + drat + wt, 
                data = x,
                family = gaussian(),
                na.action = "na.fail")
  clusterExport(clust, "data")
  dredge(g1, cluster = clust, rank = "AICc",  evaluate = TRUE)
}

dat <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(dredged = map(data, dfun))
```

Edit: Successful parallelization of dredge on nested data with Ben's solution using `doParallel`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MuMIn)
library(doParallel)

dfun <- function(x) {
  g1 <- glmmTMB(mpg ~ disp + drat + wt, 
                data = x,
                family = gaussian(),
                na.action = "na.fail")
  dredge(g1, rank = "AICc",  evaluate = TRUE)
}

dat <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()

ncores <- detectCores() - 1L
registerDoParallel(ncores)

dat_dredge <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(dat),
                      .packages = c("MuMIn", "glmmTMB"),
                      .final = function(x) setNames(x, dat$cyl)) %dopar% {
                        dfun(dat$data[[i]])
                      }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're using  `clusterExport(clust, "data")` and not `clusterExport(c("x", "g1")` ?

Comment: Ah because that was my 2nd attempt. My first was ```clusterExport(clust, "x")``` which gives an error "object 'x' not found", so I tried feeding it "data", the name of the column in the nested data frame referenced in `map()`. `clusterExport(c("x", "g1"))` gives the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility: put the model fitting and dredging within a single function, then nest/map.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(MuMIn)

dfun <- function(x) {
   g1 <- glmmTMB(mpg ~ disp + drat + wt, 
          data = x,
          family = gaussian(),
          na.action = "na.fail")
   dredge(g1, rank = "AICc",  evaluate = TRUE)
}
dat <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(dredged = map(data, dfun))
```

```
 dat$dredged[[1]]
Global model call: glmmTMB(formula = mpg ~ disp + drat + wt, data = x, family = gaussian(), 
    na.action = "na.fail", ziformula = ~0, dispformula = ~1)
---
Model selection table 
  cnd((Int)) dsp((Int)) cnd(dsp) cnd(drt) cnd(wt) df  logLik AICc delta weight
1     19.740          +                            2 -12.011 31.0  0.00  0.750
5     28.410          +                    -2.780  3  -9.825 33.7  2.63  0.201
3     18.490          +            0.3503          3 -11.965 37.9  6.91  0.024
2     19.080          + 0.003605                   3 -11.974 37.9  6.93  0.024
6     28.190          + 0.019140           -3.835  4  -7.830 43.7 12.64  0.001
7     30.650          +           -0.4436  -2.990  4  -9.702 47.4 16.38  0.000
4      8.536          + 0.022440   1.9780          4 -11.481 51.0 19.94  0.000
8     16.050          + 0.042090   2.3460  -3.989  5  -4.630 79.3 48.24  0.000
Models ranked by AICc(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ben_Bolker. However, with this approach I've been unable to implement parallel processing due to an error saying "object 'g1' not found." I've edited the main question to show my attempt. Any additional thoughts?